# How many Lagrangian subspaces are there over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $(V,\omega)$ be a finite-dimensional ($\dim(V)=2n)$  symplectic vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$. How many Lagrangian subspaces of $V$ are there? I am particularly interested in the case $q=2$.

Comment: I just want to add a note: this question is highly related to stabilizer codes in quantum error correction. Stabilizer states (code vectors of stabilizer codes) correspond to Lagrangian subspaces of $\mathbb{F_2^{2n}}$ with the standard inner products. In quantum computing literature, the wanted formula can be found derived in Gross (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0602001), also see CalderbankRainsShorSloane (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9608006).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $\prod_{i=1}^n(q^i+1)$.

To see this, we may assume that $\omega$ is represented by
$\begin{pmatrix}0&I\\-I&0\end{pmatrix}$ and let $L=\operatorname{span}\begin{pmatrix}I\\0\end{pmatrix}$ be a standard Lagrangian subspace of $V$. The symplectic group
$$
\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb F_q):=\left\{
P=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}\in\operatorname{GL}_{2n}(\mathbb F_q)
~\middle|~P^{\mathrm T}\begin{pmatrix}0&I\\-I&0\end{pmatrix}P
=\begin{pmatrix}0&I\\-I&0\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
$$
acts transitively on the set of all Lagrangian subspaces of $V$.
Recall that the $A,B,C,D$ satisfy $C^{\mathrm T}A=A^{\mathrm T}C$,
$D^{\mathrm T}B=B^{\mathrm T}D$ and $A^{\mathrm T}D-C^{\mathrm T}B=I$,
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group.
The stabilizer of $L$ is
$$
\operatorname{Stab}(L)
=\left\{
P=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}\in\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb F_q)
~\middle|~P\begin{pmatrix}I\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}*\\0\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
=\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb F_q)\cap\begin{pmatrix}*&*\\0&*\end{pmatrix},
$$
so $C=0$ and $A^{\mathrm T}D=I$. Let $E:=D^{\mathrm T}B=B^{\mathrm T}D$,
then it can be any symmetric matrix, while $D$ must be an invertible matrix.
Once $D$ and $E$ are given, we can solve $A$ and $B$ by $A=(D^{-1})^{\mathrm T}$ and $B=(D^{-1})^{\mathrm T}E$. Hence
$$
\#\operatorname{Stab}(L)=q^{n(n+1)/2}\cdot\#\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb F_q)
=q^{n(n+1)/2}\cdot\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^i)
=q^{n^2}\cdot\prod_{i=1}^n(q^i-1).
$$
For the symplectic group over finite field we have (see https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Order_formulas_for_symplectic_groups)
$$
\#\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb F_q)=q^{n^2}\cdot\prod_{i=1}^n(q^{2i}-1).
$$
Therefore the number of different Lagrangians is $\#\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb F_q)/\#\operatorname{Stab}(L)=\prod_{i=1}^n(q^i+1)$.